# Scrape Instagram data and display it in an app?

Tags: web-scraping, instagram, api-design

Is there a non-paid way to scrape Instagram data like a list of followers/following and display these lists on an app? (preferably flutter or react). If the target's account is private and I follow the target I should be able to get the data.

I've seen people do it with pre-built packages on GitHub which can fetch this data but how do we relay this information on an app like an API? Does something like this exist already? I have referred to questions similar to this here but couldn't find one specifically.

Basically, I wanna make an app that shows these lists but I don't know how to. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Yes.
B) It's not that easy.
C) Instagram is pretty quick to detect scrape attempts and issue bans.
D) You can get around it if you try hard enough, but it takes a lot of expertise, constant modification of code, and significant resources in terms of server and proxy configuration.
E) It would be very difficult to do it at any kind of scale, and the expense would increase with scale.
F) It would be against IG policy to display data you got by scraping.
G) I do not believe the API allows for obtaining follower lists at all.
H) So if you do have this data, you didn't obtain it legally and
I) Your app will probably be delisted from any platform

Sorry.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user

Comment: Makes sense, Thank you for the info.

Comment: No problem, just wish it was a better answer.